Comparing ARIMA model for Johnson & Johnson quarterly earnings vs random data
I'm trying to compare two models: one with a clear upward trend, based on non-random time series data (Johnson & Johnson quarterly earnings) and another based on completely random data:
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/marcopeix/AppliedTimeSeriesAnalysisWithPython/refs/heads/main/data/jj.csv'

df1 = pd.read_csv(url).set_index('date')
np.random.seed(1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'data':np.random.rand(len(df1))}, index=df1.index)

fit1 = ARIMA(df1, order=(2,1,0)).fit()
fit2 = ARIMA(df2, order=(2,1,0)).fit()

I'm finding that the model with random data seems to be a better fit than the model with non-random data:
fit1.aic
267.7514374521209

fit2.aic
57.83979919194317

fit1.summary()

                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ar.L1         -0.6532      0.076     -8.548      0.000      -0.803      -0.503
ar.L2         -0.1084      0.103     -1.048      0.295      -0.311       0.094
sigma2         1.3639      0.152      8.967      0.000       1.066       1.662

fit2.summary()

                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ar.L1         -0.7479      0.108     -6.943      0.000      -0.959      -0.537
ar.L2         -0.4263      0.107     -3.975      0.000      -0.636      -0.216
sigma2         0.1084      0.021      5.263      0.000       0.068       0.149

I was expecting fit2 to be a poor fit since it's based on random data, but AIC is actually lower for fit2 than fit1, and the $p$ values are also all significant.

Am I right this is J&J quarterly earnings data? If not, let you or me correct that part.

Some observations:

Since the model is the same, the degrees-of-freedom adjustment to the log-likelihood is the same, so comparing AICs is the same as comparing (negative) log-likelihoods.
Your model includes differencing the data, so any linear trends get destroyed.
The estimated variance of the second time series is much lower than that of the first time series, making the normal density much higher at its peak. If the two series were equal except for their scale (variance), their errors would be equal except for their scale. Since the likelihood is numerically equal to the joint density of errors (though the likelihood is a function of parameters while the density is a function of the data) assuming these are i.i.d., the second time series would yield the higher likelihood and the lower AIC.

I think the likely major contributor to the second time series getting a higher likelihood is the variance.

As Richard clearly pointed out, the comparison probably isn't necessarily "fair". I would fit the johnson's data and then  fit the  ( johnson's data + extra noise ) and see what happens. You should get a better fit in the former case.

Thank you @RichardHardy! But then what is really the point of looking at this table? Unless I'm misunderstanding the coefficients table, it suggests that the correlations with lag of 1 and lag of 2 are somehow important. But if random data with no structure whatsoever can lead to strong and significant coefficients, how sure can I be that the coefficients of the actual model are meaningful?

@mlofton, I don't doubt that. Still I find it very strange that modelling completely random data would show highly significant predictors...

Well, I don't know the cause exactly. It is interesting. But, random data has trends ( see granger and newbold, "spurious regressions, 1974" for a somewhat related example ) and, once you difference, you get rid of these trends. Now you're dealing with non-trending data that might have less variation than the original data. I would A) use a constant seed ( so the data doesn't change ) and B) plot the random data and see how things look.

I don't know if you can get it for free but this paper surprised a lot of people when it first came out. Not exactly the same scenario as yours but still surprising. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0304407674900347

@locus, good points, but there is a caveat. By differencing i.i.d. data you create a pattern, namely, a MA(1) process. You are approximating this MA(1) process by AR(2), and you can do that to some extent. Try fitting ARIMA(2,0,0) instead of ARIMA(2,1,0) on i.i.d. data, and you should get insignificant coefficients for most of the random seeds of generating the i.i.d. data. On an unrelated note, the paper that mlofton links to can be found here for free.

Richard has a nice idea. One other idea is to do the exact thing ( same artificial data set ) you did originally but do it without differencing ( so d = 0). See if that is worse. I suspect it will be but I don't know for sure.

Oh, and thanks to Richard for finding a free version. ScienceDirect is well known for making sure that papers don't become free so I didn't even bother to look for a free version.
